# Sed command to add text after specific work for only the first occurence

Tags: macos, sed

I want to add some words after a specific word in a file.

Example:

```
flags:ia
minfree:5
naflags:ia
```

I want to add ,lo,ad,fd,fm,-all after the "flags:ia" I used the following see command:

```
sudo sed -i.bak "s/flags:ia[^)]*/&,lo,ad,fd,fm,-all/" /etc/security/audit_control
```

however my output ends up being;

```
flags:ia,lo,ad,fd,fm,-all
minfree:5
naflags:ia,lo,ad,fd,fm,-all
```

How can I make it only effect the "flags:" and not the "naflags:" ?

Comment: Anchor your search pattern at the start of the line: `s/^flags [etc.]`, the leading `^` is what you're after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `\0` instead of `&` to address the current match in the replacement pattern:

```
sudo sed -i.bak 's/^flags:ia[^)]*/\0,lo,ad,fd,fm,-all/' /etc/security/audit_control
```

I'm not sure why you are using `[^)]*`. This might depend on you actual input data. Knowing only the input you've shown in the question I would have expected `[^[:space:]]*` instead, or nothing like that.

---

For `OSX` users. It turned out that the above command doesn't work on `OSX` (I cannot test this since I'm using `Linux`). However, we could find out in the comments belowe that the following command will work:

```
sed '/^flags:ia[^)]*/s/$/,lo,ad,fd,fm,-all/' input.file
```

Comment: the sudo sed -i.bak "s/flags:ia[^)]*/\0,lo,ad,fd,fm,-all/" /etc/security/audit_control
 did not seem to work it replaced the "flags:ia" with a "0"

Comment: Oh, I see. We need to use single quotes.. (copied that from the question).  Otherwise the shell would eat the `\\\`.. Can you check if it works for you now?

Comment: Still does not work, I am using OSX as well if that makes a difference.

Comment: Still replaces the "flags:" with a "0" and it still changes both not just the first.

Comment: Ok, I see your second concern.. I've added the `^` to the start of the pattern... Still don't get why the `\0` doesn't work. It must be a compatibility issue between OSX(BSD) sed and GNU sed .. (or bash) However, I've tested it even in `--posix` mode. Have you used the exact command I've shown?

Comment: Try `sed '/^flags:ia[^)]*/s/$/,lo,ad,fd,fm,-all/' input.file` ... does it work?

Comment: Glad to see that we've found a solution. Fortunately there are many ways to do things in `sed` :)